# What is a good first electric guitar for a newbie for $400?

Tags: electric-guitar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to check when buying a new guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/what-to-check-when-buying-a-new-guitar)

I have been playing acoustic guitar, but need now an electric one, since I cannot practice with it during late evenings.

I have been thinking about Paul Reed Smith Standard 22 and Fender Stratocaster Squier model.
However, I am not sure which to pick.
I think the guitar should be easy and simple to play, since I have played little electric guitar before.
I like the sound from the Squier models, but not sure if it is good for a newbie.

**Which electric guitar would you give for a newbie?**

Comment: Hi, shopping advice is off-topic here (see the [FAQ]) due to subjectivity and the fact that a question with enough detail about what you want is not likely to be useful to others.  We do have a couple questions on how you can evaluate guitars for yourself however, see the linked duplicate.